# Can Gedit also backup files like "Untitled Document 1"?

Tags: backup, gedit

GEdit can make backups of files that have already been saved once.

But can it make backups of files that I have just created, and **not saved yet**?
Those files are typically shown as "Untitled Document 1" etc.

*Motivation: I often create new text files to quickly write a phone number or something, and Ubuntu 2012.04 crashes quite often, so I end up loosing information sometimes.*

If GEdit can not do this, is there a similar, fast-to-start program that has this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GEdit can not do that, unfortunately.

The closest is Scribes, which has this feature enabled by default.

Geany is another text editor, it has a plugin to allow this behavior.

Comment: this would be a really neat feature!

Answer (score 0):

There are several webapps that can easily do the trick, like Google Docs.

If you don't want the online applications, then you can write anything in `vim`. If you are editing the file `filename.ext` and the computer crashes, you'll still have a swap file named `.filename.ext.swp`.

Please note that the dot(`.`) before the file name means that the file is hidden. To see the file in the file browser, you'd have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.